# How do I create a product/service through Sales and Purchase mode in Quickbooks using qbXML

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am  trying to create a service in Quickbooks using sales and purchase mode but It only creating under sales or purchase mode even though I added sales and purchase mode. Can any one please give me the solution or any work around on this will be very much appreciated.

Edition: QBOE(6.0)

Below is the way that I am following to create a service in sales and purchase mode.

Am I missing any thing or is there any thing that I need to do at QuickBooks side apart from this?

```
<ItemServiceAddRq>  
   <ItemServiceAdd>
   <Name>QBTubes</Name>
   <SalesAndPurchase>
     <SalesDesc>Tubes are excellent for all ages</SalesDesc>
     <SalesPrice>100</SalesPrice>
     <FullName>Sales</FullName>
     </IncomeAccountRef>
     <PurchaseDesc>Tubes are excellent for all ages</PurchaseDesc>
     <PurchaseCost>80</PurchaseCost>
     <ExpenseAccountRef>
     <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
     <FullName>Purchases</FullName>
  </SalesAndPurchase>
 </ItemServiceAdd>
</ItemServiceAddRq>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QuickBooks Online qbXML API does not support creating an item with sales and purchase information.

You can verify this by using the [QuickBooks OSR documentation](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html) -

- Set the OSR to use qbXML 6.0 (QuickBooks Online only supports 6.0)
- Check the 'OE' checkbox
- Uncheck the 'US' checkbox
- Choose "ItemServiceAdd" from the "Select Message" drop-down menu

The schema is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<ItemServiceAddRq>
<ItemServiceAdd> <!-- required -->
<Name >STRTYPE</Name> <!-- required -->
<ParentRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ParentRef>
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<SalesOrPurchase> <!-- optional -->
<Desc >STRTYPE</Desc> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<Price >PRICETYPE</Price> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<PricePercent >PERCENTTYPE</PricePercent> <!-- optional -->
<!-- END OR -->
<AccountRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</AccountRef>
</SalesOrPurchase>
<!-- OR -->
<!-- END OR -->
</ItemServiceAdd>
</ItemServiceAddRq>
```

Comment: .Thanks for your quick response.So is it possible in the US version of QBOE(6.0)? And also where can I find it's version like whether US or UK in Quickbooks ?

Comment: No version of QuickBooks ONLINE supports this. QuickBooks Online in the UK isn't supported at all by the API. The Windows (e.g. non-Online, the actual Windows software version) versions of QuickBooks *do* support this.